# Ionic Angular Mobile App: Create reusable plugin or library with one codebase

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, reusability

I am kind of new with Ionic Angular mobile apps and i would like to know if there is a way to build plugins or libraries or something with similar concept, **but with a single codebase.**

In my research so far i found that in order to create a plugin requires to write and maintain the web, the iOs and the android code for the plugin which makes things really hard for a developer or even a small team.

I've also saw the multi application concept, but i didn't find enough documentation in order to proceed further.

Please give your input or ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can keep all common component changes in bitbucket / git repo and will be able use them on different projects.

Comment: You can build plugin in cordova or new Ionic implementation capacitor

Comment: But as far as i know in order to build a plugin i have to write and maintain the code 3 times. 

1 for web 
1 for android
1 for iOs.

Im i correct?